# Java - How to access static synchronized method from another Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, static, synchronized, bukkit

I'm using an API that provides a `static` `synchronized` method and I need to call it from another Thread.
Always when I call it from another thread it throws an Exception with a message like that

```
Can't access this method from another thread!
```

What I tried was to put the method call into a `synchronized` block. But since it is a static method
there is nothing to put into the static block.

So how can I access a static synchronized method from another thread?

**UPDATE:** I'm coding a Bukkit plugin (minecraft) and the API is called *TagAPI*.

Comment: That seems like an API specific exception. You'll have to tell us more about it.

Comment: I'm writing a Minecraft Plugin with Bukkit. And the API I'm using is called **TagAPI**.

Comment: Hope you are using Class.methodName

Comment: you need to get Thread which method has associated to(invoked by), if it's a library and everything is going from your code(no lib separated thread, etc.) so it's not hard work, just keep the dependent thread alive and call the method with it. this [example](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#trpool) would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [the library checks that you are calling the method from a specific thread](https://github.com/KittehOrg/TagAPI/blob/master/src/main/java/org/kitteh/tag/TagAPI.java), then most likely there is a good reason for that, and therefore you should not do it.